# How to download a static excel file using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to provide a link to download a file via Rails. These are my questions:-

1. Where do you place the static file under public?
2. Are there any simple controls which allows me to download this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need rails for this. If the file is in public, your web server should serve it automatically.

You just need to know the URL so that you can link to it from your app.

Doesnt really matter where you put it within public, but pick somewhere that will let you keep organized as you add more.

Comment: If your file is accessible to authenticated users only then you should put elsewhere on your file system and do some IO. Check http://www.therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right/